# Sliding Tab Positioning CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

I need help in positioning my Sliding TAB. It does work and looks good on my browser...  But when viewed on other computer with different resolution. It overlaps the other tab.

Here's the site.. [LINK](http://gosystems.com.au/)

Here's my code..

CSS**

```
    .slide {
        position: fixed;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 300px;
        margin: 1em 0;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        top: 230px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 999999;
    }
    .slide .inner {
        position: absolute;
        left: -270px;
        top: 0;
        width: 300px;
        color: #333;
        z-index: 999999;
    }
    .scontent {
        float: left;
        width: 251px;
        background: #fff;
        height: 200px;
        padding: 10px;
        z-index: 999999;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #bbb;
        border-right: none;
    }
    .mybutton {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        float: left;
        width: 25px;
        height: 147px;
        background: url(images/remotesupporttab.jpg) no-repeat #fff;
        ;
        z-index: 999999;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 7px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 7px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 7px;
        border-top-right-radius: 7px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
        border: 1px solid #bbb;
        border-left: none;
    }
```

JS**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#slideleft .mybutton').click(function() {
        var $lefty = $(this).parent();
        $lefty.animate({
          left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
          -$lefty.outerWidth() + 31 :
          0
        });
      });
    });  

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like, your 'customersure_tab' is positioned in percentage and the other tab is in fixed px (top: 230px;)